# Any Mp3 organizer which can replace album with folder name

Tags: batch, mp3, windows-xp, batch-rename

I have Huge Mp3 collection . i want that a software which can replace

```
1)Filename with Title
2)Foldername with Album
```

I am using Windows XP SP3

Comment: what OS is that?

Comment: windows xp sp3 d

Comment: -1 for stolen mp3s //missing additional -1 for not using google

Comment: @Mic have u paid for all ur mp3 on hard drive??

Comment: I don't have a single mp3 on my hdd because I hate the bad quality. The only music files I own are .flac lossless rips of my own cd collection.

Comment: @Mic how do u put flac in ipod

Comment: I do not have an iPod, I own a creative Zen XF-I 2, wich is capable of the .flac format.

Comment: @Michael K: Stolen??? Are you an omniscient policeman? How do you know?

Comment: I am pretty sure about this, nearly every huge mp3 collection is illelgaly downloaded.
"@Mic have u paid for all ur mp3 on hard drive??" - Well, that confirmed my thoughts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes - you can use [mp3tag](http://www.mp3tag.de/en/) to do that - it has a filename to tag option that works well for this - you'd need to use a string like /%album%/t%title% to do it.

Comment: can i do batch basis . e,g i have 100 folders and subfolders. it select parent folder and it does all

Comment: yes. E:\music\%album%\%title% as your arguement for the tag-filename will put everything in folders by album, and title as filename, under e:/music . - test it on some files, and you can use the same command on everything. Just remember to hit the save option once its done

Comment: @Donkey: c'mon, for the time it took you to write this comment, you could have opened the web site, and see that the first thing mentioned there is "Batch processing". And it's about the same time to download and try it.

Comment: i knew about batch renaming but i was not sure about foldername to album thing

Answer (score 0):

[EasyTAG](http://easytag.sourceforge.net/)

> EasyTAG is a utility for viewing and editing tags for MP3, MP2, MP4/AAC, FLAC, Ogg Vorbis, MusePack, Monkey's Audio and WavPack files. Its simple and nice GTK+ interface makes tagging easier under GNU/Linux or Windows.
>
> Features of version 2.1:
>
> ...
>
> - Ability to rename files and directories from the tag (using masks) or by loading a text file,